# MySQL: How can I count visitors per page per day?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an interesting query here. I have a table that stores visitor's `ip` and `page_id` along with a timestamp (`date`). I would like to count the amount of visitors per day for each `page_id` so I can then take that output and calculate which `page_id` is trending (on a daily basis)

Table `visitors_counter` looks like this:

```
id|page_id | ip    | date
1 |   37   |1.1.1.1| 2017-02-10 14:03:16
2 |   38   |1.2.1.1| 2017-02-10 11:04:16
3 |   39   |1.1.3.1| 2017-02-10 16:05:16
4 |   37   |1.5.1.1| 2017-02-10 17:08:16
5 |   37   |1.1.1.1| 2017-02-10 19:07:16
```

And what I would like to achieve would be something like:

```
id|page_id |visitors | date
1 |   37   |3        | 2017-02-10 14:03:16
2 |   38   |1        | 2017-02-10 11:04:16
3 |   39   |1        | 2017-02-10 16:05:16
```

So far I've been able to count the amount of unique visitors per day with

`SELECT DATE(date) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT page_id) uniqueperday 
FROM visitors_counter 
GROUP BY DATE(date)`

i know im close, but its not quite what I want as I don't know which `page_id` are the most visited ones

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your result you should use    the group by and count(*)   (you have two times the same id for page 37 and want result 3)

```
SELECT DATE(date) Date, page_id, COUNT(*) visitperday 
FROM visitors_counter 
GROUP BY DATE(date), page_id
```

othewise  the Giorgios is the right one

Comment: This is what I needed. As an extra question, would it be possible to count not only on a daily basis but also every X amount of hours? lets say every 3 hours get the amount of visitors per page?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `page_id` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT DATE(date) Date, page_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) uniqueperday 
FROM visitors_counter 
GROUP BY DATE(date), page_id
```

The above query returns the number of unique `ip` visits per page per day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation on page and date to find count of distinct visitors per page per day. Also, use user variables to generate sequence id.

```
set @id := 0;

select @id = @id + 1 id,
    page_id,
    count(distinct ip) visitors,
    min(date)
from visitors_counter
group by page_id, DATE(date)
order by visitors desc, page_id;
```